# Can one preposition directly follow another in a sentence?

Tags: prepositions

Can one preposition directly follow another in a sentence? The sentence in question is:  "I am so impressed by the one-on-one time that we can **take advantage of with** the executives-in-residence program." I can just change the sentence, but I was also wondering about the rules of grammar in regards to this case.

Comment: Right or wrong, it's very, very awkward to read.

Answer (score 4):

Other types of sentences I can think of which may exemplify a case where one preposition follows another in the same phrase belong, of course, to the category in which a second preposition, for collocation reasons, is placed right after a preceding one which, in turn, in part and parcel of a phrasal or multiword verb, as in:

"My brother always **looks up to** my father: he's like a reference point to him."
"The sniper carefully **zeroed in on** the target assigned."

L2 Pre-Intermediate students often find similar examples rather tricky when they need to trasform them into the passive voice, as they tend to forget to keep the second preposition.

Answer (score 2):

There's nothing ungrammatical about it: it's just a coincidence that the phrasal verb *take advantage of* is followed by *with*. However, as waiwai933♦ has sugggested, it's not very elegant, partly because of the preceding *one-on-one time*. Cases such as this are not to be confused with complex prepositions like *in place of, up to* and *except for*, which can be used without hesitation.

Comment: Isn't it also important to note that there's a clause between the prepositional phrase 'with the executives-in-residence program' and its antecedent, 'the one-on-one time'? Don't prepositional phrases need to complete their relations within a single clause? It's interpretable as is but wouldn't it be better, more grammatically correct, as "I am so impressed by the one-on-one time with the executives-in-residence program, that we can take advantage of ." or even better: "I am so impressed that we can take advantage of (*by) the one-on-one time with the executives-in-residence program, "